# Retrieving flag = 0?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a table in a page which has an actin button, when clicking the button what i want is the file flag would be set into 0 in the database table of that file and that file would be inserted in another table called archive, I got trouble with making it since I don't know how to retrieve that same file and insert it in the archive table, any help please, I'm doing it symfony2, .? ?

Here is the function i'm using :

```
    public function rejectedTransFielArchiveAction(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $transaction = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransaction')->findDocument($transactionId);

    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $username = $user->getUsername();
    $date = new \DateTime(date('Y-M-d H:m:s'));

    $rejectedTransArchive = new Edi997DetailsArchive();

    foreach ($transaction as $key) {
      $senderId = $key->getSenderId();
      $receiverId = $key->getReceiverId();
      $IsaNumber = $key->getIsaNumber();
      $transactionDate = $key->getTransactionDate();
      $gsNumber = $key->getGsNumber();
      $fileName = $key->getFileName();
    }

    $rejectedTransArchive->setSenderId($senderId);
    $rejectedTransArchive->setReceiverId($receiverId);
    $rejectedTransArchive->setIsaNumber($IsaNumber);
    $rejectedTransArchive->setTransactionDate($transactionDate);
    $rejectedTransArchive->setGsNumber($gsNumber);
    $rejectedTransArchive->setFileName($fileName);

    $em->persist($rejectedTransArchive);
    $em->flush();

    if ($transactionId != null) {
      $transDetail = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransactionDetail')->getDetails($transactionId);

      foreach($transDetail as $key) {
        $transDetailArchive = new EdiTransactionDetailArchive();

        $transDetailArchive->setEdiTransactionId($transactionArchive->getEdiTransactionId());
        $transDetailArchive->setRefNumber($key->getRefNumber());
        $transDetailArchive->setPoNumber($key->getPoNumber());
        $transDetailArchive->setInvoiceNumber($key->getInvoiceNumber());
        $transDetailArchive->setAsnNumber($key->getAsnNumber());
        $transDetailArchive->setAdjNumber($key->getAdjNumber());
        $transDetailArchive->setAmount($key->getAmount());

        $em->persist($transDetailArchive);
      }
    }

      $removeTransaction = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransaction')->findOneByEdiTransactionId($transactionId);
      $em->remove($removeTransaction);

      $em->flush();

      $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
      $session->getFlashbag()->add('message', $fileName.' has been archived.');

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('matrix_edi_view'));
  }
```

Comment: i'll update my question with the function i'm using @Dagon